# How can I use template parameter name outside the class?

Tags: c++

I am learning c++.
I would like to use template parameter name as it is outside the class.
I could not find the best solution but now I use "using" declaration. However it cannot use same name.
 Are there any better solution? Or Are there any good habit or good naming  to re-declare template parameter by "using"?

The following code are example; it re-declare T_TypeA by using Type = T_TypeA but I would like to use T_TypeA as it is in struct B.

```
template <typename T_TypeA>
struct A {
    using Type = T_TypeA;
};

template <typename Object>
struct B {
    using Type = typename Object::Type;
    Type object = 3;
};

void test_using_for_template_parameter_name(void) {
    B<A<int>> b;
    std::cout << "value = " << b.object << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The following code are example; it re-declares `T_TypeA` by using `Type =
>   T_TypeA` **but I would like to use `T_TypeA` as it is in struct B**.

template parameter names are only useful and visible within the *function template* or *class template*, they have no meaning outside it. So:

```
template <typename T_TypeA>
struct A {
    using Type = T_TypeA;
};
```

`T_TypeA` here only serves as a placeholder name for the *type* used as template argument when instantiating `struct A`.

This is why we need typedefs to alias the name of the type. so, if `T_TypeA` is the name you want visible: you may want to:

```
template <typename TypeA>
struct A {
    using T_TypeA = TypeA;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to use T_TypeA as it is in struct B.

I don't think there is a way to do that. Your best option is what you have already done.

```
using Type = T_TypeA;
```

and

```
using Type = typename Object::Type;
```